# Attach link to 'URL' cell of table created with JS Array in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hyperlink

I have created a table using a JS array for a web directory. I was hoping to have the URL cell actually be a link to another page in the directory.

Here is the function to create the table:

```
<script>
function TableofStars()
{
  var Stars= [
    {
      "Name": "Orion",
      "Category": "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "7",
      "Sub-Stars": "81",
      "Symbol": "The Hunter",
      "Area": "594",
      "B-Star": "Rigel",
      "URL": "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Orion/"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ursa Major",
      "Category": "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "20",
      "Sub-Stars": "93",
      "Symbol": "The Great Bear",
      "Area": "1280",
      "B-Star": "UMa",
      "URL": "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Ursa_Major/"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ursa Major",
      "Category": "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "20",
      "Sub-Stars": "93",
      "Symbol": "The Great Bear",
      "Area": "1280",
      "B-Star": "UMa",
      "URL": "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Ursa_Major/"
    }
  ]
var col = [];
  for (var i=0; i < Stars.length; i++){
    for (var key in Stars[i]){
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1)
      {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++)
{
  var th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = col[i];
  tr.appendChild(th);
}

for (var i = 0; i < Stars.length; i++)
{
  tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++)
  {
    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
    tabCell.innerHTML = Stars[i][col[j]];
  }
}

var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
</script>
```

Is this also the best way to create the table? I got the general idea from another stack overflow thread but I could be wrong thinking this is the best way to do it.

Let me know if any more information is needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that table format, sure.

This code will give you a link to the url provided in the object.

The additional part just checks if the value being put into the cell is the 8th item in the object, and if so sets the href of an `<a>` tag to the url. You can change this if your data structure changes, and you can obviously change the text of the Link. I called the function at the end just to get things rolling.

```js
function TableofStars()
{
  var Stars= [
    {
      "Name": "Orion",
      "Category": "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "7",
      "Sub-Stars": "81",
      "Symbol": "The Hunter",
      "Area": "594",
      "B-Star": "Rigel",
      "URL": "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Orion/"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ursa Major",
      "Category": "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "20",
      "Sub-Stars": "93",
      "Symbol": "The Great Bear",
      "Area": "1280",
      "B-Star": "UMa",
      "URL": "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Ursa_Major/"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ursa Major",
      "Category": "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "20",
      "Sub-Stars": "93",
      "Symbol": "The Great Bear",
      "Area": "1280",
      "B-Star": "UMa",
      "URL": "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Ursa_Major/"
    }
  ]
var col = [];
  for (var i=0; i < Stars.length; i++){
    for (var key in Stars[i]){
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1)
      {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++)
{
  var th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = col[i];
  tr.appendChild(th);
}

for (var i = 0; i < Stars.length; i++)
{
  tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++)
  {
    if (j === 7) {
    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
    tabCell.innerHTML = `<a href="${Stars[i][col[j]]}">Link</a>`

    } else {
    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
    tabCell.innerHTML = Stars[i][col[j]];
    }
  }
}


var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);
}

TableofStars();
```

```html
<div id="showData"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Had a feeling the it would include the <a href=""></a> just wasn't sure where to implement it. Yeah the function is called within a button just didn't want to add too much code.

Comment: No prob! Enjoy 

Comment: Hi there, sorry for late comment. When I run the code on the site and click the first URL link I get sent to a 404 page... the url for that page is "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/$%7BStars[i][col[j]]%7D" this doesn't seem right?

Comment: @Mia.B it sounds as though the object only has that chunk of the url in it- this code sticks whatever that field is as the href for the a tag. Are you able to inspect the data returned from the server to see if it's shortening the url, or inspect the link with Chrome dev tools, to ensure that it's set correctly before you click it?

Comment: Also, some browsers "help" the user by removing the "http://", visually, from the displayed url. This may be what you're experiencing.

Comment: "5.69.151.182 - - [18/Oct/2018 19:39:29] "GET /constellations/$%7BStars[i][col[j]]%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -
" that's what i'm getting from the server window. When inspecting the page on waterfox it does say that the requested url is :"http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/${Stars[i][col[j]]}".. ?

Comment: Hm- it seems to work by running the code snippet above. It looks like the name of the constellation is being replaced, maybe you're using that, or a reference to it, as a variable name? Unfortunately I can't diagnose further without seeing the context of the code.

Comment: The table is created fine I just don't understand the url when clicking the link. Im using python flask to route urls with html templates . I would have thought with this code it would take whatever is in the "URL": row into the hre="" but then why does it just show the code in the url?

Comment: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol." thats also what it says in the web console if that helps in any way..

Comment: Checkout the first entry on this thread, see if it helps =) https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1

Comment: I added this to the <head> in my base.html file but hasn't made a difference

Answer (score 0):

An alternative;

```js
function TableofStars() {
  var Stars = [
    {
      Name: "Orion",
      Category: "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "7",
      "Sub-Stars": "81",
      Symbol: "The Hunter",
      Area: "594",
      "B-Star": "Rigel",
      URL: "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Orion/"
    },
    {
      Name: "Ursa Major",
      Category: "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "20",
      "Sub-Stars": "93",
      Symbol: "The Great Bear",
      Area: "1280",
      "B-Star": "UMa",
      URL: "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Ursa_Major/"
    },
    {
      Name: "Ursa Major",
      Category: "Modern",
      "Main-Stars": "20",
      "Sub-Stars": "93",
      Symbol: "The Great Bear",
      Area: "1280",
      "B-Star": "UMa",
      URL: "http://set09103.napier.ac.uk:9111/constellations/Ursa_Major/"
    }
  ];

  let table = document.createElement("table");
  //Create Column
  let colHeading = [];
  Stars.forEach((item, i) => {
    Object.keys(item).map((key, i) => {
      if (colHeading.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        colHeading.push(key);
      }
    });
  });

  //Create Heading
  let tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  colHeading.map((item, i) => {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = item;
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });

  //Create Cell
  Stars.map((item, i) => {
    let tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    colHeading.map((el, i) => {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      if (el === "URL") {
        tabCell.innerHTML = `<a href=${item[el]}>${item[el]}</a>`;
      } else {
        tabCell.innerHTML = item[el];
      }
    });
  });

  let divContainer = document.getElementById("app");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Not a problem. Here to help.